# Input type of time in cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have added a new field of type time in my db, since my controller was already baked ,i didnt want to bake it again.If i do so, my existing changes will vanish. 
I want the input type of time format, but when i see it in front end, its coming as textbox.
Given below is my Entity:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;

/**
 * BlackOutDay Entity
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property int|null $day
 * @property int|null $topic_id
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenDate|null $date
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime|null $from_time
 * @property \Cake\I18n\FrozenTime|null $to_time
 * @property bool $full_day
 */
class BlackOutDay extends Entity
{
    /**
     * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
     *
     * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
     * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
     * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_accessible = [
        'day' => true,
        'topic_id' => true,
        'date' => true,
        'from_time' => true,
        'to_time' => true,
        'full_day' => true
    ];
}
```

Model :

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

/**
 * BlackOutDays Model
 *
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay get($primaryKey, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay newEntity($data = null, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay[] newEntities(array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay|bool save(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay saveOrFail(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay patchEntity(\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface $entity, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay[] patchEntities($entities, array $data, array $options = [])
 * @method \App\Model\Entity\BlackOutDay findOrCreate($search, callable $callback = null, $options = [])
 */
class BlackOutDaysTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->setTable('black_out_days');
        $this->setDisplayField('id');
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
    }

    /**
     * Default validation rules.
     *
     * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
     * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator
            ->integer('id')
            ->allowEmptyString('id', 'create');

        $validator
            ->integer('day')
            ->allowEmptyString('day');

        $validator
            ->integer('topic_id')
            ->allowEmptyString('topic_id');

        $validator
            ->date('date')
            ->allowEmptyDate('date');

        $validator
            ->time('from_time')
            ->allowEmptyTime('from_time');

        $validator
            ->time('to_time')
            ->allowEmptyTime('to_time');

        $validator
            ->boolean('full_day')
            ->allowEmptyString('full_day');
        return $validator;
    }
}
```

Since i had added the field later i had manually added

```
$validator
    ->time('from_time')
    ->allowEmptyTime('from_time');

$validator
    ->time('to_time')
    ->allowEmptyTime('to_time');
```

And i have initialized the property too.

Comment: Have you checked which changes would occur if you "bake" it again?

Comment: Actually i have modified the code according to my feature. So if i bake it again then it will override my existing code change. That's y i don't want to bake the table again.

Comment: That's fine. Commit your code to the repository (or save it otherwise), bake again and check for differences. Then apply the changes you need to the original code

Comment: But that's a shortcut. I want to know y its not working.

Comment: That's not a shortcut. If you know that it works when you generate the code automatically, you can check for the differences

Comment: Clear your model cache (`tmp/cache/models`).

Comment: That was the first thing which i did. Not working.